# Геос-3М бинарный протокол

Tags: python

Пытаюсь вывести Геос-3М из бинарного протокола. От него получать данные в этом протоколе получается, но в на команды не реагирует. Устройство RaspberryPi, ОС Rasbian. Код на питоне:

```
import serial
import struct
import time
aport = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
ser = serial.Serial(aport, 115200,timeout=1)
com = b'\x47\x45\x4f\x53\x72\x33\x50\x53\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc5\x$
ser.write(com)
while True:
        rx = ser.read(size=512)
        print("RX: " + str(rx))
ser.close()
```